# jquery - too much recursion - if.clause

Tags: jquery, events, if-statement, submit, clause

before a submit-action is fired i´m doing a little check before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var check = $("#check").val();

        if(check == 1) {
            $("#submit").submit();
        } else {
            alert"input-hidden value is wrong")
        }

}

});
});
```

So i am checking if a value of a input-hidden-value is set to 1.

If it is, the form action should be processed, but instead i get this error:

```
too much recursion
```

anybody could help with this?

EDIT:

In this line:

```
$("#submit").submit();
```

this part:

```
#submit
```

is underlined, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because calling `$("#submit").submit();` again triggers the submit event which will again invoke the submit handler thus creating an infinite recursive loop... call the dom elements submit method instead like `this.submit()`

or use the preventDefault() only if the value is invalid else allow the default action to continue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").submit(function (e) {
        var check = $("#check").val();
        if (check != 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("input-hidden value is wrong")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `$("#submit").submit()` to allow submit to happen, this causes your handler to be called over and over. Instead, you should move `preventDefault()` after the error alert() and return true instead of calling submit().